# Switch-case making NOT statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
class dd
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
            {
                short dd = 5;
                switch (dd)
                    {
                        case !1:
                        case !2:
                        case !3:
                        case !4:
                            System.out.println("Pf");
                    }
            }
    }
```

So I have this small part of code, I know it is wrong, all I want to know is how I can make the `if ( SomeVariable ! = SomeNumber )` using the `swtich-case` command. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd have to use `default` for that within your cases.

Comment: In addition to the `switch-case` answer (given below), you could do something like `if (!Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).contains(dd)) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A case cannot be about not-something. But you can use the `default:` case instead:

```
short dd = 5;
switch (dd)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            break;
        default:
            // matched none of the above cases
            System.out.println("Pf");
    }
```